# Is there a cheap(er) way of getting Pro Tools 11?

Tags: pro-tools

I've been forced to buy Pro Tools a few times over the years, and as a result have a few versions...the last being 7.3.1 LE, with the complete production toolkit.

I've avoided buying it again every version number, but I think I'll have to do it again this month.

So - is there a good upgrade path that I could exploit to get 11 (not HD)?

Thanks anyone who replies!

Tom
(existing user, haven't registered here yet!)

Comment: In my experience Avid are pretty good at pointing you in the best direction. I'd just call them and explain your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the student option if you are a student. ($300) 
There is the crossgrade upgrade if you have the previous version, but if you are too many versions behind you will have to buy it for about the same price. 
I would recommend buying from sweetwater.com or americanmusicalsupply because they offer 3 - 8 monthly payments to split up the cost. Another great way to get the newest version and still get a deal, Buy the Eleven Rack from Sweetwater ($699) and you will get a great guitar amp simulator and a free copy of the latest pro tools. [elevenrack link](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/ElevenRack/)
If you want to score a free copy, find out where AVID is doing some product testing or consumer group meetings and attend and give them some input. They usually hook you up with something great!

Best of Luck!

- Krux

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the reason that you need to upgrade? And if you've upgraded to 7.3 LE the last time, what does 'over the years' mean? 
Asking for ways to exploit an upgrade path sounds like doing possible illegal stuff. Probably not the best to talk about that on an online forum.....

Comment: Well there was a version 1 - they maybe skipped some versions - i went from 7.3, to 8, and now I'm holding for a while until 11 or beyond makes sense to me.  Not everyone religiously updates to the latest version - some stages still run on v6 or v7!  Please don't assume they're looking for an illegal way when they may be in similar shoes as many, including myself - finding the most cost effective way to upgrade (in what is already a myriad of convoluted upgrade paths and caveats thanks to Avid) and not also be giving Avid our first born child to get current.

Comment: I myself have learned that what used to cost about $700 for an upgrade to get the features I needed (during PT9 era, but there was a technical reason I couldn't upgrade) has ballooned into a $4000 upgrade now to get the EXACT SAME features which cost only $700 more 1-2 years ago.  So I share the same sentiment as the OP of wanting to find the cheapest upgrade path possible.  And I, would never consider doing so illegally. Assuming/accusing others without fact is what the forum, in my opinion, does not need.  I feel there's enough of that on DUC and Gearslutz as it is already.

Comment: Hi Stavro, thanks for your response. I wasn't accusing him, i was asking because he used the word 'exploit' which can point in two directions, if you get what I mean. And it was more 'a word of advice' than anything else. Which is something forum is good for. 
Looking back perhaps my tone was a bit harsh, which was not my intention. And i totally agree on your statement about avid's upgrade paths. I've been in pt9 (with 2nd hand CPTK) for a while and it suits my purposes just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a crossgrade price from Pro Tools LE.

http://shop.avid.com/store/product.do?product=325865714841120

That's the best you're going to get. The other cheapest way is if you're a student to get the student discount, that one comes with 4 years of upgrades free as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the CPTK (do you have V1 or 2), you might be able to find a used 9 or 10 license on Ebay and then do the upgrade to 11 after that.  Starting with 11, the CPTK doesn't exist so you will either need to go to 11HD or go to regular 11 and lose the VCA's, some automation features and the multiple videos.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about saving some money, there are often deals on the Mbox with PT bundle, so just sell the Mbox after and you'll have somewhat of a discount. If you are still enrolled as a student or you teach, then the educational path is available to you. Beyond that, I'm with Arnoud, this is not the place to ask about how to exploit the system. Talk to your local PT rep and see what they can do for you.